# DynamoDB insert (put) item - return the item created?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In my Python script I insert a record (item) into DynamoDB table, but I realized the response from AWS doesn't include the actual item inserted:

```
{'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPHeaders': {'connection': 'keep-alive',
   'content-length': '2',
   'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0',
   'date': 'Fri, 27 Jan 2017 23:31:22 GMT',
   'server': 'Server',
   'x-amz-crc32': '234324243',
   'x-amzn-requestid': 'xxxxxxxxxx'},
  'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
  'RequestId': 'xxxxxxxxxx',
  'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

This is unfortunate as I have logic like:

```
if not user.exists():
    user = create_user()
else:
    user = get_user()

user.do_something()
```

and I'd rather not do another round trip just to get the user object I just inserted.

I can, of course, mock the object since using `boto3` in Python the `user` object is just a dictionary-like thing, but it's nice to be able to just use a single representation. Also it seems like the `put_item` call

```
r = user_table.put_item(Item={'user_id': uid, 'info' : { ... }})
```

should be able to return the put'd item? Or some other endpoint can?

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the property `ReturnValues='ALL_NEW'` on your `put_item` request to get the item back in the response. As documented [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.put_item)

**Edit:** The documentation is wrong, `ALL_NEW` isn't accepted for `put_item`. Since you have the exact item in memory as the parameter you passed to `put_item`, you really don't need it to be returned.

Comment: I'm confused though, the docs clearly state that "The ReturnValues parameter is used by several DynamoDB operations; however, PutItem does not recognize any values other than NONE or ALL_OLD .". I understand you're saying PutItem does accept 'ALL_NEW'. Are the docs outdated then?

Comment: Actually, I've found an [open issue](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1150) on this. It looks like 'ALL_NEW' isn't valid for put_item after all, or am I missing something?